# host doing unnecessary dns lookup for localhost

Tags: linux, networking, dns, centos

I have a centOS system(embedded and has very binaries) with the following /etc/hosts.

```
$cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost
```

Also the host is assigned a DNS server which returns some invalid IP for the domain name lookup of *localhost*. But I cannot avoid a connection to this DNS due to some network restrictions.

My question is, when I already have a valid /etc/hosts file why is the system querying the DNS for *localhost*? And how can I stop that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that you have `files` listed before `dns` for the `hosts` entry in [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf).

```
[me@home]$ grep "^hosts" /etc/nsswitch.conf 
hosts:      files dns
```

If `dns` comes first, then your system will always query DNS to resolve hostnames before falling back to `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Worked like a charm :)